# How can I rewrite the Reverse Comparator to a generic Type?

Tags: java, generics

I have a comparator which sort arrays after a given column reverse. I wish, this comparator not works just for int[], it can also work for other number types. How can I do it?

the Code of the comparator is here:

```
public class ReverseComparator implements Comparator<int[]> {

int col;

public ReverseComparator(int col) {

    this.col = col;

}

@Override
public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {

    if (a[col - 1] > b[col - 1]) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a[col - 1] < b[col - 1]) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

}
```

I changed it, but it always wrong, i have no idea...

```
public class ReverseComparator implements Comparator<T extends Number[]> {

int col;

public ReverseComparator(int col) {

    this.col = col;

}

@Override
public int compare(T[] a, T[] b) {

    if (a[col - 1] > b[col - 1]) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a[col - 1] < b[col - 1]) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: 'it always wrong' mean not sorted properly ?

Comment: He wants to sort arrays of anything. You can't extend Number[], which is why it's wrong

Comment: @Youngistan no, the first comparator is all right, it just work for int[]. The second Comparator doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to make the `ReverseComparator` generic, then you've to declare the type parameter with it. And give the bounds to it:

```
public class ReverseComparator<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T[]> {
     @Override
    public int compare(T[] a, T[] b) {
        // Write your comparison logic here
        // Note that just normal arithmetic operators won't work here.
    } 
}
```

I've given two bounds to the type parameter, as we only want to compare numbers that are comparable. Giving `Comparable<T>` as second bound allows you to use `compareTo()` method for comparison.

Also note that, this is not going to work for primitive type arrays, for example, `int[][]`. You have to have `Integer[][]`, or `Float[][]`, etc.

Comment: I tried this code, but if I give the following code, it told me wrong: public int compare(T[] a, T[] b){ if( a[1] > b[1]) {return -1;} } The error is：The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s), do you know what's wrong with it?

Comment: I tried this code, but if I give the following code, it told me wrong: public int compare(T[] a, T[] b){ if( a[1] > b[1]) {return -1;} } The error is：The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s), do you know what's wrong with it?

Comment: @xirururu Did you read my comments in the code? I clearly wrote, arithmetic operators won't work here. You have to use `compareTo()` mthod.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a solution in the Java library: `Collections.reverseOrder` which optionally takes another Comparator.

This works for all objects implementing the Compareable interface:

```
  public class ColumnComparator<T> implements Comparator<T extends Compareable[]> {

    // Should not change in the middle of the comparison
    final int col;

    public ColumnComparator<T>(int col) {

        this.col = col;

    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T[] a, T[] b) {
    // Watch it! Possible null pointer if a[col-1] == null! Change as it suits yourself
    // The generic implements the Comparable interface. Use it.
    return a[col -1 ].compareTo(b[col-1]);

    }

  }
```

Then, chain an instance of your comparator with the reverse comparator:

```
  Comparator<ClassYouWantToCompare[]> columnComparator = new ColumnComparator<ClassYouWantToCompare[]>(1);
  // Reverse the odering of the comparator.
   Comparator<ClassYouWantToCompare[]> result = Collections.reverseOrder(columnComparator);
```

This will simply result in `result.compareTo(Compareable a, Compareable b) == -1 * columnComparator.compareTo(T a, T b)` but it is fare more readable.

Comment: the code of ColumnCompartor are wrong. The Error is: “Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ">", { expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token "extends", , expected”

Comment: I forgot the parameterization of the class (ColumnComparator<T>). I've updated the code, it should now work.